# How to avoid blocking a .NET thread when waiting for requests

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I have a server application that is listening on a `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`. It blocks on the `Socket.Accept()`, tying up the thread. What is a good way to relinquish control of the thread, yet yield the result of the computation to the calling client?

The server code, somewhat cleaned up, looks like this:

```
void ManeLupe(Socket socket)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        Socket client = null;
        NetworkStream stm = null;
        try 
        {
            client = socket.Accept();             // Blocks thread
            stm = new NetworkStream(client);
            var response = ProcessRequest(stm);   // this could take a while
            WriteResponse(response, stm);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(client, ex);
        }
        finally
        { 
            if (stm != null) stm.Dispose();
            if (client != null) client.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

My constraint, currently, is that the code has to run on .NET framework 3.5, so I can't take advantage of the new-fangled `Task<>` and `async` goodness. Frankly I'm rather new to asynchronous programming in general, which I'm suspecting is going to be the answer to this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket provides Asynchronous variant of Accept called [BeginAccept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginaccept%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is what you're after.

`BeginAccept` is the APM implementation of Accept, It provides a pair of methods for each operation. In this case you'll be using `BeginAccept` and `EndAccept`.

As noted in comments by @CoryNelson you might consider using [AcceptAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.acceptasync%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as well. It is upto you to choose which one.

Comment: @CoryNelson Yes, true. Personally I don't like that eventing (EAP) model. I'll add it in my answer, thanks.

Comment: Indeed, depends on the use. AcceptAsync is low-level for perf. Of course, APM isn't much better in terms of usability.

Answer (score 0):

```
     You can use AcceptAsync and register to the callback to do your processing after the accept is completed. Simple example below

           void ManeLupe(Socket socket)
            {

                var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                args.Completed += Accept_Completed;
                socket.AcceptAsync(args);
            }

            void Accept_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                //do your processing here
            }
```